# Change / Exchange values in textboxes on text change in jquery

Tags: jquery, events, textbox, onchange, swap

Scenario : I have a series of text boxes with with unique numbers. If I change the value in a text box to another value, then any other text box having value same as this value will have their values swapped.

The below code works for 2 textboxes for first time but not when i try to swap them again.

```
<input type="text" name="txtseq" id="txt1" value="6"></input><br>
<input type="text" name="txtseq" id="txt2" value="5"></input><br>
<input type="text" name="txtseq" id="txt3" value="4"></input><br>
<input type="text" name="txtseq" id="txt4" value="3"></input><br>
<input type="text" name="txtseq" id="txt5" value="2"></input><br>
<input type="text" name="txtseq" id="txt6" value="1"></input><br>
<input type="text" name="txtseq" id="txt7" value="7"></input><br>

var old = "";

$("document").ready(function () {
  $("input[type='text'][name*='txtseq']").focus(function(){
      old = $(this).val();
});

$("input[type='text'][name*='txtseq']").change(function () {       
    var vl = $(this).val();        
    if (vl != "" && parseInt(vl) > 0) {
        ChangeSeq(vl);
    } else {
        $(this).val(old);
        return;
    }
  });
});


function ChangeSeq(val) {   
  var v = $("input[type='text'][name*='txtseq'][value='" + val + "']");
  $(v).val(old);   
}
```

[Find the code in JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/chandandaslipun/ZYpbS/)

Comment: `input` is a selfclosing element so `<input/>`.

Comment: thanks .. but i strongly believe it wont solve the issue ...

Answer (score 2):

First input is self closing element as commented in the post.

Next you are trying to get the value based on the `HTML` **value attribute** .

There is a subtle difference between the `property` and `attribute` of the element.

The attribute part never changes and it is always set to the initial value defined in `HTML` unless an until manipulated explicitly.

When the change is triggered `value` property changes but not `HTML` `attribute` value.That is the cause for the issue in your case.

So you would need to set the attribute property of value if you want this working.

And you can use `attribute starts with selector` to select the inputs directly.

**Code**

```
var old = "";


$("document").ready(function () {
    $inputs = $('[id^=txt]');
    $inputs.focus(function () {
        old = $(this).val();
    });

    $inputs.change(function () {
        var vl = $(this).val();
        if (vl != "" && parseInt(vl) > 0) {
            // Need to pass the current element as the 
            // attribute has to be set
            ChangeSeq(vl, this);
        } else {
            $(this).val(old);
            return;
        }
    });
});


function ChangeSeq(val, elem) {
    var v = $("input[type='text'][name*='txtseq'][value='" + val + "']");
    // Need to set the attribute property
    $(v).attr('value', old);
    // Need to set the value attribute of elem to val
    $(elem).attr('value', val);
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZYpbS/2/)**

Comment: Thanks @Sushanth. Nicely explained. Here's how I was doing it.
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/chandandaslipun/rHqAc)